# Random code snippet showing up in browser

Tags: php

I have this random closing tag showing up in my top left header above the first navigation

```
**);**
```

Can't find it in the header of the page or the index.php. My only thought is it's being added from some plugin or inserted ad

website: https://americanmotorcyclist.com/

Comment: start disabling your plugins one by one and see if it goes away.  I would start with the plugin your using for ads.

Comment: i can see it's going wrong in the google analytics part. the first script isn't closed and thats why the second script fails as well. Fixing this might fix the problem.
https://snipboard.io/Fq9WYB.jpg

Comment: I think you are correct. Thanks for tha!